# Custom ListView DataTemplate Binding / XAML Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I wanted to create a friendlist for my WPF MVVM (Light Toolkit) Application, which will get filled from database generated User Objects (in ObservableCollection or List?) and should be displayed as following:

[image]

I'm using MahApps Metro and would use Tiles in a WrapPanel for each alphabetic Letter. But now I can't figure out how I correctly build the DataTemplate for the ListView.

So if my Code is totally wrong, how could I correctly create the View (from image above) in XAML with DataBindings as you can see in the example code?
Would be a GridView better?

My XAML (FriendlistView):

```
<UserControl
<!-- Stuff -->
DataContext="{Binding Friendlist, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid Background="White">
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FriendsCompleteList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Friends}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Letter}"/>
                                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <controls:Tile Title="{Binding Path=Username}"
                                                       TiltFactor="2"
                                                       Height="100" Width="100">
                                            <Image Height="40" Width="40"/>
                                        </controls:Tile>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<!-- Just Closing Tags -->
```

My FriendlistViewModel as DataContext:

```
public class FriendlistViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private List<FriendlistPart> _friendsCompleteList;

    public FriendlistViewModel(List<FriendlistPart> friendsCompleteList)
    {
        FriendsCompleteList = friendsCompleteList;
    }

    public List<FriendlistPart> FriendsCompleteList
    {
        get { return _friendsCompleteList; }
        set { Set(ref _friendsCompleteList, value); }
    }
}

public class FriendlistPart
{
    public string Letter { get; set; }
    public IList<User> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

And my MainViewModel to Display it with Test Data:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var userList= new List<User>{
            new User { Username = "test" },
            new User { Username = "test1" },
            new User { Username = "test2" }
        };

        var friendlistCompleteList= new List<FriendlistPart>
        {
            new FriendlistPart { Friends = userList, Letter = "A" },
            new FriendlistPart { Friends = userList, Letter = "B" },
            new FriendlistPart { Friends = userList, Letter = "C" }
        };

        CurrentPageViewModel = new FriendlistViewModel(friendlistCompleteList);
    }
}
```

---

### **Edit:** Tried Example from @Ilan with Mvvm Light and tweaked it:

My projectstructure is like this:

- Model

  - User
  - FriendlistSection
- View

  - FriendlistView
- ViewModel

  - FriendlistViewModel
  - MainViewModel
  - ViewModelLocator

I created the ListView in FriendlistView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Messenger4u.View.FriendlistView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Messenger4u.Model"
         xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:messenger4U="clr-namespace:Messenger4u"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}">
    <ListView x:Name="ItemsPresentingListView" Margin="0, -5, 0, 0" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FriendlistComplete}" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <messenger4U:IgnoreMouseWheelBehavior />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:FriendlistSection}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="0, 5, 0, 5" Text="{Binding Path=Letter}" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Black" Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="-2, 0, 0, 0" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <controls:Tile Title="{Binding Username}"
                                                               TiltFactor="2"
                                                               Height="100" Width="100"
                                                               Margin="8, 15, 15, 15"
                                                               Background="DodgerBlue">
                                                    <Image Height="40" Width="40" Source="../Skins/Images/user.jpg"/>
                                                </controls:Tile>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

FriendlistViewModel:

```
public class FriendlistViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<FriendlistSection> _friendlistComplete;

    public FriendlistViewModel(List<FriendlistSection> friendlist)
    {
        FriendlistComplete = new ObservableCollection<FriendlistSection>(friendlist);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FriendlistSection> FriendlistComplete
    {
        get { return _friendlistComplete; }
        set { Set(ref _friendlistComplete, value); }
    }
}
```

FriendlistSection:

```
public class FriendlistSection : ObservableObject
{
    private string _letter;
    private ObservableCollection<User> _friends;

    public string Letter
    {
        get { return _letter; }
        set { Set(ref _letter, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Friends
    {
        get { return _friends; }
        set { Set(ref _friends, value); }
    }
}
```

User:

```
public class User : ObservableObject
{
    private string _username;

    public string Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set { Set(ref _username, value); }
    }
```

MainViewModel:

```
public MainViewModel()
    {
        var userList = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User {Username = "test"},
            new User {Username = "test1"},
            new User {Username = "test2"}
        };

        var userList1 = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User {Username = "test3"},
            new User {Username = "test4"},
            new User {Username = "test2"},
            new User {Username = "test5"},
            new User {Username = "test6"},
            new User {Username = "test7"},
            new User {Username = "test8"},
        };

        var userList2 = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User {Username = "test9"},
            new User {Username = "test10"},
        };

        var friendlistCompleteList = new List<FriendlistSection>
        {
            new FriendlistSection {Friends = userList, Letter = "A"},
            new FriendlistSection {Friends = userList1, Letter = "B"},
            new FriendlistSection {Friends = userList2, Letter = "C"}
        };
        // Can use var, but here was my mistake to create the 
        // FriendlistViewModel as ViewModelBase
        FriendlistViewModel friendlistViewModel = new FriendlistViewModel(friendlistCompleteList);
        CurrentPageViewModel = friendlistViewModel ;
    }

    // Bound to ContentControl in MainWindow
    public ViewModelBase CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentPageViewModel; }
        set { Set(ref _currentPageViewModel, value); }
    }
```

ViewModelLocator:

```
static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<User>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<FriendlistSection>();

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<FriendlistViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    public FriendlistViewModel Friendlist => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<FriendlistViewModel>();
```

Now it works fine, added the IgnoreMouseWheelBehaivior, because it gets handled by a ScrollViewer and set the WrapPanel Width to ActualWidth from the Grid that gets sized trough the ScrollViewer in MainWindow.

Thanks again to @Ilan!

Now it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try the next:

**Xaml code:**

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewDataTemplateContainingListViewAndMore.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:listViewDataTemplateContainingListViewAndMore="clr-namespace:ListViewDataTemplateContainingListViewAndMore"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="This">
<Window.DataContext>
    <listViewDataTemplateContainingListViewAndMore:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}">
    <ListView x:Name="ItemsPresentingListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FriendsCompleteList}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type listViewDataTemplateContainingListViewAndMore:FriendlistPart}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition ></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Letter}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                                <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Fill="Black" Height="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Rectangle>
                                <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" BorderBrush="#00FFFFFF">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="500"/>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Rectangle Width="120" Height="120" Fill="Blue"></Rectangle>
                                                    <Ellipse Width="90" Height="90" Fill="Tomato"></Ellipse>
                                                </Grid>
                                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <Run Text="Name: "></Run>
                                                    <Run Text="{Binding Username}"></Run>
                                                </TextBlock>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox></Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

1. You don't need the GridView (you don't have any table).
2. Use the ListBox instead the ItemsControl to allow selection.
3. Set the WrapPanel width to see the wrapping working (optional).
4. I don't have Tile control, thus I've used rectangle to simulate it.
5. Please take in attention that a Grid (named "LayoutRoot") provides the DataContext for the ListView (named "ItemsPresentingListView").

**Here are a modified view models (please take in account the [next article](http://magicaldebugging.com/top-3-memory-leak-inducing-pitfalls-of-wpf-programming/))**

```
public class FriendlistViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<FriendlistPart> _friendsCompleteList;

    public FriendlistViewModel(List<FriendlistPart> friendsCompleteList)
    {
        FriendsCompleteList = new ObservableCollection<FriendlistPart>(friendsCompleteList);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FriendlistPart> FriendsCompleteList
    {
        get { return _friendsCompleteList; }
        set { Set(ref _friendsCompleteList, value); }
    }
}

public class FriendlistPart:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _letter;
    private ObservableCollection<User> _friends;

    public string Letter
    {
        get { return _letter; }
        set
        {
            _letter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Friends
    {
        get { return _friends; }
        set
        {
            _friends = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class User:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _username;

    public string Username
    {
        get { return _username; }
        set
        {
            _username = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    private FriendlistViewModel _currentPageViewModel;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var userList = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User {Username = "test"},
            new User {Username = "test1"},
            new User {Username = "test2"}
        };

        var userList1 = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User {Username = "test3"},
            new User {Username = "test4"},
            new User {Username = "test2"},
            new User {Username = "test5"},
            new User {Username = "test6"},
            new User {Username = "test7"},
            new User {Username = "test8"},
        };

        var userList2 = new ObservableCollection<User>
        {
            new User {Username = "test9"},
            new User {Username = "test10"},
        };

        var friendlistCompleteList = new List<FriendlistPart>
        {
            new FriendlistPart {Friends = userList, Letter = "A"},
            new FriendlistPart {Friends = userList1, Letter = "B"},
            new FriendlistPart {Friends = userList2, Letter = "C"}
        };

        CurrentPageViewModel = new FriendlistViewModel(friendlistCompleteList);
    }

    public FriendlistViewModel CurrentPageViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentPageViewModel; }
        set
        {
            _currentPageViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**How it looks like:**
[image: here]

Regards.

Comment: @Daniel please see how it looks like.

Comment: Looks great, thanks for your efforts! I'll try it out.. so my main mistakes were to not set the DataType and not using ObervableCollection apart from my xaml

Comment: @Daniel much more, use the Compare Beyond to compare ListView controls in my and your code . Let me know if you need explanations.

Comment: tried your example and postet it above, but got an exception for _Generics.List_ not in Cache for SimpleIoC..

Comment: @Daniel try to debug the FriendlistViewModel c'tor and let me know what do you see there.

Comment: got it to work, my mistake is marked with a comment in MainViewModel.. tweaked your xaml and added solution

Comment: @Daniel Good. Let me know if my example was helpful.